# How can I add menus to Flex Viewer 2?

Tags: arcgis-flex-api, arcgis-flex-viewer

I have a lot of widgets and my dashboard in Flex Viewer 2 has gotten cluttered. How can I add menus to the dashboard rather than buttons to organize the widgets?
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add your widgets to the config="widgets/HeaderController/**HeaderControllerWidget.xml

Source:
http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapps/flexviewer/live/apps/config-wgcontainers.xml

Good Example
http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapps/flexviewer/live/index.html

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply but I am not blessed with the answer yet. The 'Good Example' link does not work. It pops up message saying 'SWF is not a loadable module'. Please can you provide me another good example link or something useful.

Comment: Good Example link does work on all computers (4 of them) that I have access to.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **<widgetgroup>** to group several widgets shown in the HeaderController into one group/folder.

You can see a live example at
http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapps/flexviewer/live/index.html?config=config-all.xml

It's also described in the documentation at
http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapps/flexviewer/help/index.html#/Widgets_in_the_ArcGIS_Viewer_for_Flex/01m30000001v000000/
http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapps/flexviewer/help/index.html#/The_Widget_Container_tag/01m300000003000000/

```
<widgetcontainer layout="float">
    <widgetgroup label="Locators">
        <widget label="Find U.S. address"
            icon="assets/images/i_target.png"
            config="widgets/Locate/LocateWidget_US.xml"
            url="widgets/Locate/LocateWidget.swf"/>
        <widget label="Find European addresses"
            icon="assets/images/i_pin2.png"
            config="widgets/Locate/LocateWidget_EU.xml"
            url="widgets/Locate/LocateWidget.swf"/>
        ...
    </widgetgroup>
</widgetcontainer>
```